# loop.run_until_complete gives "TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required"

Tags: python, async-await

I have following code which communicate to socket and receive data from server and which works fine. But when the program exit I am getting some error and the program not exit and it stay forever.

```
 async def on_shutdown():
    # close peer connections  
    for pc in pcs.values():
         await pc.close()
    pcs.clear() 
    print("on shutdown exit...")

    #coros = [pc.close() for pc in pcs]
    #await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    #pcs.clear() 

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(signalingServerConnect(args))
   
    finally:
        # cleanup
        
        loop.run_until_complete(await on_shutdown)
        print("Exit...")
```

Below error I am getting when I exit the code. What could be the reason.
**Error:**

```
loop.run_until_complete(on_shutdown)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 563, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 592, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was withe the code

```
    loop.run_until_complete(await on_shutdown)
```

I replaced it with

```
    loop.run_until_complete(on_shutdown())
```

And the error message goes away.